# Why does SQL workbench always return a row full of null values in every query?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, mysql-workbench

Every query has a final row with an asterisk beside it and null values for every field? Why does this show up? I cant seem to find an explanation for it. Even putting a WHERE clause doesnt seem to get rid of it. Is this only happening to the MySQL implementation alone?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is for inserting a new row, you enter the values there.

Comment: Does this mean it is ok/normal to have a row of NULLs when displaying a table?

Comment: @Sanglang yes, the row should have an asterisk (*) in the left side

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it's not just the data entry row. Usually when viewing the table data in something like Workbench or SQLYog, it will display the rows of data, plus a blank row at the end that is used for adding new data. It will show NULL for each column if that is the default value for that columns data type

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you can type the values directly when you click on the box instead of writing “insert into…” in your query tab