# MySQL NULL row added after I added a Primary Key to existing table

Tags: mysql

I had an existing table and added a primary key using this command

```
ALTER TABLE account add column account_id INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, ADD PRIMARY KEY    (account_id);
```

After I did this, every time I do a SELECT * on this table using  MySQL Workbench, the last row shows NULL in every column, even though two of their columns are set to NOT NULL.

If I do SELECT * from the command line, I don't see this empty row.

I then did the following in workbench

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE Name IS NULL
```

and it does return the empty row. The same command in the command line gives 0 results.

Any idea why workbench is showing me this extra row after I added a primary key? Thanks!

Comment: What you're seeing is probably just how Workbench displays its rows. If you SELECT *, does it not give you a blank row so you could add data right there in the interface? I think that's what you're seeing, and on the command line you are only seeing the rows that are actually in the table.

Comment: In other words, isn't that row there for you to _type values into_?

Comment: It seems that's what it is! For some reason I'm certain this wasn't showing up before. But yes, it allows me to type values in and then click apply to run the equivalent command. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does SQL workbench always return a row full of null values in every query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075237/why-does-sql-workbench-always-return-a-row-full-of-null-values-in-every-query)

Comment: @philipxy this is a 6 year old question, but thanks :)

Comment: After a couple of recent duplicates I went searching for the earliest & found this so marked it too. If closed as a duplicate, people will be sent to the earlier one & otherwise the comment will send them there. Although comments here give the right answer, a post with an answer & votes is also better, this doesn't have an answer. So the closure/comment is for others & the future, not 6-yrs-ago you.