# How to remove null from results

Tags: sql

I have this SQL statement:

```
select 
    v.venue_id, v.name
from
    venues v
where 
    not exists (select e.vid
                from events e
                where e.vid = v.venue_id);
```

Here is the result of the query:

[image: result of SQL statement, has venue id in one column and name in the other]

It works fine but the last row in the result is null, how do I remove that? Been trying for a bit now with no luck

Comment: I'd rather ask why venue_id can be nullable?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Can I prevent it from being nullable?

Comment: Isn't that just the next and as of yet empty line in your GUI tool that shows that the columns are `null` since nothing has been entered yet? Is that really a row that's been returned from the table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does SQL workbench always return a row full of null values in every query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075237/why-does-sql-workbench-always-return-a-row-full-of-null-values-in-every-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you're experiencing
[Why does SQL workbench always return a row full of null values in every query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075237/why-does-sql-workbench-always-return-a-row-full-of-null-values-in-every-query)
Looks like that's normal behavior

Comment: Yeah I think this is it. Seems to match up. Will mark this as closed as soon as S.O lets me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The null row is per design, disregard it. i thought you were firstly referring to a column.
on your where statement `<field> is not null`

So:

```
select v.venue_id, v.name
from venues v
where not exists (
    select e.vid
    from events e
    where e.vid = v.venue_id 
    and name is not null 
);
```

Comment: Which one, there are two

Comment: Note that venue_id is a column, not a field.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the post, unfortunately, I am still getting the null result.

Comment: check the updated answer.